# C# Change content-disposition with webclient

Tags: c#, upload, webclient, content-disposition

I would like to upload a file on a specific website with C# and the WebClient class. I have this code :

```
 Console.Write("\nPlease enter the URI to post data to : ");

            String uriString = "http://www.noelshack.com/api.php";
          //  String uriString = "http://127.0.0.1/upload.php";


            WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
            string fileName = lst_path[0];
            byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadFile(uriString,"POST", fileName);

            MessageBox.Show("\nretour:" + System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray));
```

But the problem, on the website the name of the file input is "fichier" and webclient send "file" as name .

I would like it to send :

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fichier"; filename="csharp.jpg"
instead of :
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="csharp.jpg"

I didn't find how to modify this filed, some help please ?

Comment: Decompiling `System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile`, which uses `System.Net.WebClient.OpenFileInternal`, shows that `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="` is hardcoded. You will need to use another method.

Answer (score 0):

If you have .NET 4.5+, you can use the `HttpClient` class to do an asynchronous post:

```
async Task<string> UploadFileAsync(string[] lst_path)
{
    string uriString = "http://www.noelshack.com/api.php";
    string fileName = lst_path[0];
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    using (StreamContent sc = new StreamContent(fs))
    {
        form.Add(sc, "fichier", fileName);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uriString, form);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: i downloaded httpclient via http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c  but there is an error on the word "await"  -> "await doesn't exists in this context"  http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/16/1397765605-error.png